# Why is this "%s" not allowed with value inside of pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, printf

I know that pointer and exactly same to each other. The program below shows an error if i use %c and then loop through all the values of the string then i see no error but with %s i get an error.
Also if i use array i place of pointer and use arr[] with i see an error. Like arr[] = "Hello" and then use printf("%s", arr[]); .......i see an error too. What is wrong here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main()
{
char *ptr = "Hello";

printf("%d\n", ptr);
printf("%s\n", *ptr);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow Rule of Thumb #2: If the OP asserts "I know that", he doesn't.

Comment: "I know that pointer and ____ exactly same to each other". Is there a missing word here? Also, is the second sentence missing some punctuation as it seems to say that the program shows an error but that you see no error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both calls of `printf` result in undefined behavior:

- Passing a pointer for a parameter printed with `%d` is not allowed
- Passing a non-pointer (in this case, that's a `char`) to `%s` is undefined behavior as well. It is likely to cause a crash because a non-pointer gets dereferenced.

In order to print a value of a pointer, cast the pointer to `void*`, and use `%p` format specifier:

```
printf("%p\n", ptr);
```

In order to print a string, pass `ptr`, not `*ptr`, to a parameter with `%s` format specifier:

```
printf("%s\n", ptr);
```

Comment: causes illegal dereference of non-pointer? Nope, you are toast earlier just like with the other one.